# O que significa o sufixo _t e quando utilizá-lo?

Tags: c, c++, tipagem, convenções-de-nome

Vejo em muitos códigos algumas variáveis com o sufixo `_t`. Existe um monte de exemplos na biblioteca padrão do C como `size_t`, `int32_t`, `mbstate_t`.

Qual a utilidade, e quando utilizar este sufixo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É um convenção que indica que aquele nome representa um tipo de dados (t de *type*). É usado para não confundir com outros identificadores de códigos.

Até onde eu sei foi criado para evitar conflitos com código existente já que originalmente esses tipos não existiam e alguém poderia ter usado esses nomes em alguma coisa no código, o que daria problema na compilação. Alguns consideram que é apenas para deixar mais claro que é um tipo e não uma variável.

Em códigos seus não costuma ser tão útil usar assim e é raro vermos as pessoas usando em seus tipos. O mesmo vale para bibliotecas. Particularmente acho quase todas as convenções do C ruins e mal pensadas, algumas entendo porque, mas não concordo.

Eu prefiro usar tipos com maiúsculos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Para complementar a resposta do @Maniero:

É uma convenção (humana) pra dizer que é tipo.

O padrão C89 define `size_t`, `wchar_t`, `off_t`, `ptrdiff_t`, entre outros. O C99 define coisas como `uintptr_t`, `intmax_t`, `int8_t`, `uint_least16_t`, `uint_fast32_t`, etc.

Arquivos de interesse, para dar uma espiadinha nas definições: `stdint.h`, `inttypes.h`, `stdint.h`

Exemplo:

```
typedef struct {
  char* model;
  int year;
...
} car_t;
```

Veja uma menção nessa referência:

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html

E pergunta similar no SOzão:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/231760/916193